# show class for only clicked item angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng-class

I don't know how to set visible class only for clicked item in partial component. So, I've temaplate with:

```
<div class="photo-container" *ngFor ="let i of modalImages; let index = index">
       <div [ngClass]="ImageContainer">
           <i class="ionicons ion-ios-close remove-icon" (click)="deleteImageEvent(index)"></i>
           <img (click)="onImageClickEvent(index)" src="{{ i.thumb }}">
       </div>
</div>
```

In component I'm initialised them..

```
export class ImageModal implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('reviewFileInput') reviewFileInput: ElementRef;
    @Input('modalImages') public modalImages: any;
    @Input('imagePointer') public imagePointer: number;
    @Output('cancelEvent') cancelEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Input('imageClass') public imageClass: any;
    ...
```

Then in that next template let him call "add-photo-component" which I want to use this class i'm declaring next:

```
<ImageModal #imageModal
                       [modalImages]="images"
                       [isReviewPhotos]="true"
                       [imageClass]="classMap"
                       (cancelEvent)="cancelImageModel()"
                       [options]="options"
                       [isUploadButtonAvailable]="isUploadButtonAvailable"
                       (clickEvent)="onUploadClick()"
                       (handleEvent)="handleNgUpload($event)"
                       (deleteEvent)="deleteImage($event)"
                       (handleSelectedImgEvenet)="onImageClick($event)"
                       (imageContainer)="{'img-media-container': isImageSelected}"> // And this class which I want to use 
</ImageModal>
```

then in component add-photo-component I want to set this hided class on clicked image

```
onImageClick($event) {
        if ($event && $event.index >= 0) {
            this.selectedImage = this.images[$event.index];
            this.isImageSelected = !this.isImageSelected;
        }
    }
```

styles:

```
.img-media-container{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #4774c5;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

So how can I apply class only on one selected item. I know that somehow I need to take an index from main template, but I dont have any ideas how I can realized that.

Comment: On which element you want to add class ? what is your partial component ? on the click element in your *ngFor ?

Comment: correct me, partial component is that where i'm using <ImageModal #imageModal....></ImageModal>. And in this component I want to add class

Comment: I guess that you do it completely wrong. I see some mistakes. Could you publish whole ImageModal Component and parent where you trying call this component?

Comment: @JaroslawK., updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your post is messy and I dont know which code belong to which component. But add class depending on selected element is simple and always look similarly. Try in this way:

```
<div *ngFor ="let image of modalImages; let index = index">
       <div [class.img-media-container]="image === selectedImage" >
          <!-- some code -->
       </div>
</div>
```

You can find the same example code in [official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html) from Angular creators.
Search in chapter: *Style the selected hero*

Comment: I updated my topic, please check it again. Variable selectedImage is in add-photo-component, and this code is from ImageModal component.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty cool in angular 2. The idea to do that is create and initialize an array. While clicking the div the index of the div should be pushded inside the initialized array. And add this class to the div which only satisfy the condition.

**For getting index.**

```
<div class="photo-container" *ngFor ="let i of modalImages; let index = index"></div>
```

**For adding CSS Class**

```
   <div [class.ImageContainer]="array[i]=i">
       <i class="ionicons ion-ios-close remove-icon" (click)="deleteImageEvent(index)"></i>
       <img (click)="onImageClickEvent(index)" src="{{ i.thumb }}">
   </div>
```

(ImageContainer is class name and array[i]=i is the condition)

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html
go to the link for more details